# FEC and Gianfar deriver

Tags: linux, driver, ethernet, powerpc

What is the difference between fec and gianfar driver? It does not seems to be chip drivers. I have to integrate the functionality of DP83849 PhyChip for MPC8313E. I have one fec driver ported for coldfire architecture and uses DP83849 phy. Can I use fec driver or for MPC8313E, gianfar is required?

Answer (score 1):

After going through drivers, I figured out these are the drrivers supported for different ethernet speed. fec is for fast ethernet and gianfar supports upto 1gbps. It mainly depands on the type of processor used.